# Discrete Math, Injective, Surjective

Tags: discrete-mathematics, functions

I am trying to understand a question I got:

Let $U$ be a set.

For every $A\subseteq U$ we define the function: $f_{A}:P(U) \to P(U)$ such as $f_{A}(B)=(A\cap B)$.

Prove: $f$ is injective and surjective if and only if $A=U$

First, I do not understand what $f_{A}$ and $f_{A}(B)$ mean.

I think that if I will understand this, I will be able to start solving the question.

Any tips will be wonderful!

Thanks!

Comment: It is the map that associates to each $B\subseteq U$,  the intersection $A\cap B\subseteq A$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's take an example, maybe that helps.

Start with $U=\Bbb N$ and the subset $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$. Now we have a function $f_{\{1,2,3,4,5\}}$ that takes sets of natural numbers as input, and yields sets of natural numbers as output. It works by taking the input set, and intersecting it with $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$. So, for instance:
$$
f_{\{1,2,3,4,5\}}(\Bbb N)=\{1,2,3,4,5\}\\
f_{\{1,2,3,4,5\}}(\text{the odd natural numbers})=\{1,3,5\}\\
f_{\{1,2,3,4,5\}}(\text{the primes})=\{2,3,5\}\\
f_{\{1,2,3,4,5\}}(\text{the perfect squares})=\{1,4\}\\
f_{\{1,2,3,4,5\}}(\text{the two-digit numbers})=\varnothing
$$

Comment: Thank you so much! If you have more time to look at my reply I will very appreciate that!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Arthur for your kind reply!

So, in the above question, $f$ takes inputs from $B$, intersect with $A$, and the output must be $(A\cap B)$?

Assuming (negative) $f$ is injective and surjective and $A\neq B$.

$A\subseteq U$ so $A\in P(U)$, and also $U\in P(U)$.

So $f_{A}(A)=(A\cap A)=A$ and also $f_{A}(U)=(A\cap U)=U$,

Am I going the right way?

Comment: Except that $A\cap U = A$, you're well on your way. In fact, your last line there is an important part of the proof of injectivity (we have $f_A(A) = f_A(U)$, so for this map to be injective we must have $A = U$). It remains to show that $f_U$ is indeed an injective function.

Comment: Thank you so much Arthur! :)